# Angular access/change nested ng-controller variable?

Tags: angularjs

I have a partial view which is included on multiple pages. That Partial view has it's on NgController. 
Is there a way I can access a scope variable of that specific nested controller when I'm inside of another?

For example:

```
<div ng-controller="fooController">

    <a ng-click="changeScopeVariableOfBarController()">Click!</a>

    <div ng-controller="barController">
        {{ thisHasToChangePlease }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Is that possible? I couldn't figure out how. I include the partial view with php's include, so I don't work with templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reusable "component" (template + functionality) you could refactor that into a directive instead of template + controller.  Then, using an isolated scope with parameters you could have the outside world change the inside of the directive that way.

http://plnkr.co/edit/6JYVucuizmPkyt2CLQtr?p=preview

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="fooController">
  <div>variable: {{ variable }}</div>
  <button ng-click="changeScopeVariableOfBarController()">Click to increment variable on both scopes!</button>
  <bar this-has-to-change-please="variable"></bar>
</div>
```

**bar.html**

```
<div>
    thisHasToChangePlease: {{ thisHasToChangePlease }}
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
app.controller('fooController', function($scope) {
  $scope.variable = 1;

  $scope.changeScopeVariableOfBarController = function () {
    $scope.variable++;
  };
});

app.controller('barController', function ($scope) {

});

app.directive('bar', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      thisHasToChangePlease: '='
    },
    controller: 'barController',
    templateUrl: 'bar.html'
  }
});
```